# How to re-install a npm dependency in Openshift Nodejs app?

Tags: node.js, express, openshift

My nodejs app is working fine locally but failing on OpenShift with error "Cannot call method 'get' of undefined" at below line:

```js
var express = require('express');
var controller = require('./api.controller');

var router = express.Router();
router.get('/', controller.index); // throws exception
```

Investigating the issue further, it seems version of Express is too old on my OpenShift app and I need to uninstall and install Express dependency.
Could not find any docs on OpenShift to uninstall and install a dependency from a nodejs app?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you push sources to openshift, it's automatically updates all packages according to dependencies listed in the package.json file.
You should be sure that package.json contains all necessary dependencies.

Comment: Thanks Artem. I was missing the version info for the express npm package. I updated the version number of express in dependencies list of package.json to "express": "~4.9.0" and pushed to openshift. That solved my problem.